# Symfony/Doctrine Searchable Behavior : How to override search function?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, searchable

Here is the thing, I have implemented the searchable behavior on my symfony project and it's working fine. The problem is when I try to perform a search with two words or more. The query generated by the search function is like:

```
SELECT COUNT(keyword) AS relevance, id FROM table_index 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table_index WHERE keyword = 'foo') 
AND id IN (SELECT id FROM table_index WHERE keyword = 'bar') 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Because the search uses a AND clause, these two words have to be part of a same item to be relevant. Though to modify the behavior of the search I would like to override the search function. But because the table_index generated by doctrine is not declared on my schema.yml, I'm not able to perform query on it.

Is there an other way to do it ?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my bad, I thought that accessing the table_index was impossible because not declared on my schema.yml, but actually it is, thanks to the searchable line.

In my search function,Instead of

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('COUNT(e.keyword) AS relevance, e.id')
   ->from('Table_Index t');
```

I just had to remove the _ in  the name of the index table

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('COUNT(e.keyword) AS relevance, e.id')
   ->from('TableIndex t');
```